# Is it possible to switch base vectors in the representation $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}: \mathbb{R}^{m}\oplus\mathbb{R}^{n}$ in the context of the rank theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I need clarification on a step on the proof for the rank theorem in real analysis. For completeness' sake, here is the local form of submersions as stated in the book I'm following:

(LOCAL FORM OF SUBMERSIONS) Let $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^{m},\;U\subset \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ an open set, strongly differentiable at $a \in U$, write $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}=\mathbb{R}^m\oplus\mathbb{R}^n$ and $a = (a_1, a_2);\;a_1\in\mathbb{R}^m,\;a_2\in\mathbb{R}^n,$ and let $ \partial_2f(a)=f'(a)|\mathbb{R}^n$ be an isomorphism (that is, let $f'(a):\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$ be surjective). Then there exist open sets $Z \ni a, Z \subset \mathbb{R}^{m+n}; V \ni a_1, V \subset \mathbb{R}^m; W \ni f(a), W\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a homeomorphism $h:V\times W\to Z$, strongly differentiable at $(a_1,f(a))$ s.t. $fh(x,w)=w\;\forall(x,w)\in V\times W$.

It states the rank theorem the following way:

(RANK THEOREM) Let $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^{m+p},\;U\subset \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ an open set, $f \in C^{k} (k \geq 1)$, and $f'(x)$ has constant rank = m in all of U. For each point $a \in U$, there exist diffeomorphisms $\alpha$, from an open set in $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$ to an open neighborhood of a, and $\beta$, from an open neighborhood of f(a) in $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^p$, both $\alpha$ and $\beta \in C^k$, s.t. $\beta\circ f\circ\alpha:(x,y)\mapsto(x,0)$

PROOF. Set $E = f'(a)\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$. Obviously $\mathrm{dim}\;E = m$. Let $\pi:\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be the projection onto the first coordinate. Then $(\pi\circ f)'(a)=\pi \circ f'(a):\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is surjective. From the local form of submersions, there exists a homeomorphism $\alpha \in C^k$ from an open set in $V_0 \times W \subset \mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$ to an open neighborhood of a, s.t. $\pi f \alpha (x,y) = x$ [...]

It was precisely this part that got me confused. In the local form of submersions, the homomorphism h was s.t. $fh(x,w) = w$, the second coordinate, and in the rank theorem, $\pi f \alpha (x,y) = x$, the first coordinate. At first this tripped me a bit, but I believe I understand what is happening: in the former, f went from an m + n dimensional space to an n dimensional one, and in the latter, $\pi \circ f$ went from an m + n dimensional space to an m dimensional one. Is there no problem in switching the order of the base vectors, so that I represent $\mathbb{R}^{m + n}$ rather as "$\mathbb{R}^{n + m}$", so that I can write instead $\pi f \alpha (y, x) = x$? I wish to add this step to my notes so I do not get confused later, but I am not sure my reasoning is correct.